# Can't add users to Azure DevOps project

Tags: azure-devops

Totally new to DevOps and am getting stuck in the very first steps.   I have been able to login, and create an organization and a project.  All works well for me except when I go to add a user to the team - I enter their email, and I get a status back of:

> "Users with the same email domain as the backing tenant can only be
>   added if they are members of your organizations Azure Active
>   Directory"

I'm not sure where to proceed from here... as background, most of the computers here all have office, and the user in question has a Visual Studio account.

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem. You need to add that user to your organization's Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the users to your Azure AD tenant.

You can do this 2 ways

- [You can add the users directly to your Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory)
- [You can invite the users by B2B into your Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/add-users-administrator)