# How to add users to Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We  have created project in Azure DevOps.
i joined as admin.
I created a new project and a new git repo. 
Now I wanted to add users from my org (with same domain name). But then my org email exchange is NOT online its inhouse.
Can I still add users (email id) and it will work?

I checked this link: [Can't add users to Azure DevOps project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542534/cant-add-users-to-azure-devops-project)

and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory

is that means I need to Purchase Azure account also?

Comment: have you tried this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Comment: question is not how to Add, question is Who will validate / Authenticate these added  users?

Comment: Did you get any error message when you tried adding users? Could you explain more about the question `Who will validate / Authenticate these added users` in above comment?

Comment: because my exchange is in house

Comment: Can that user access other resources of microsoft? If not, you can't add this account?